# how can we merge strings based on a key data

Tags: r

I have a data like this

basically I am trying to merge all section parts and have an output like this

```
df<- structure(list(position = structure(c(6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15", 
"2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", 
"4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18", "TP<AMB88", "TP<AMT55", 
"TP<ELANE", "TP<RACK1"), class = "factor"), col = structure(c(15L, 
6L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 14L, 9L, 18L, 16L, 8L, 13L, 4L, 2L, 17L, 7L, 
12L, 1L, 10L), .Label = c("EQMTLRGTLKGHNGW", "GRRLACLFLACVLPA", 
"GSLSNYALLQLTLTA", "LGRRLACLFLACVLP", "LSNYALLQLTLTAFL", "MGSLSNYALLQLTLT", 
"MTEQMTLRGTLKGHN", "MTLGRRLACLFLACV", "MVKETTYYDVLGVKP", "QMTLRGTLKGHNGWV", 
"SLSNYALLQLTLTAF", "TEQMTLRGTLKGHNG", "TLGRRLACLFLACVL", "TP<AMB88", 
"TP<AMT55", "TP<ELANE", "TP<RACK1", "VKETTYYDVLGVKPN"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

each section title starts with  **TP<**
The first column shows the position of each letter. 
The first column is the position of each letter

So lets take the first section data

```
TP<AMT55                                       TP<AMT55
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15          MGSLSNYALLQLTLT
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16         GSLSNYALLQLTLTA
3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17        SLSNYALLQLTLTAF
4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18       LSNYALLQLTLTAFL
```

basically it was like the following but chopped it up to different sets. So I want to merge all of the above and get the following

```
TP<AMT55                                            TP<AMT55
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18          MGSLSNYALLQLTLTAFL
```

now I am trying to put back all those letters and get the above

for example if we look at this

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
MGSLSNYALLQLTLT
3
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
GSLSNYALLQLTLTA
```

1 correspond to M in first one 
2 correspond to G (both in first and second)
3 corresponds to S (both in first and second ) etc

```
 out<- structure(list(position = structure(c(6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15", 
"2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", 
"4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18", "TP<AMB88", "TP<AMT55", 
"TP<ELANE", "TP<RACK1"), class = "factor"), col = structure(c(15L, 
6L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 14L, 9L, 18L, 16L, 8L, 13L, 4L, 2L, 17L, 7L, 
12L, 1L, 10L), .Label = c("EQMTLRGTLKGHNGW", "GRRLACLFLACVLPA", 
"GSLSNYALLQLTLTA", "LGRRLACLFLACVLP", "LSNYALLQLTLTAFL", "MGSLSNYALLQLTLT", 
"MTEQMTLRGTLKGHN", "MTLGRRLACLFLACV", "MVKETTYYDVLGVKP", "QMTLRGTLKGHNGWV", 
"SLSNYALLQLTLTAF", "TEQMTLRGTLKGHNG", "TLGRRLACLFLACVL", "TP<AMB88", 
"TP<AMT55", "TP<ELANE", "TP<RACK1", "VKETTYYDVLGVKPN"), class = "factor"), 
    join = structure(c(7L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "MGSLSNYALLQLTLTAFL", 
    "MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGWV", "MTLGRRLACLFLACVLPA", "MVKETTYYDVLGVKPN", 
    "TP<AMB88", "TP<AMT55", "TP<ELANE", "TP<RACK1"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

Comment: Care to describe what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have no idea about amino acids. All I see in your question is a before and after data frame with no explanation in between...how do you get your output?

Comment: @Sotos what do you think now?

Comment: oh ok. Now I understand what you need! Let me give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to take the last letter of all entries and paste it on the 2nd entry, considering that you split on your groups (each group defined by `TP`).

```
#make sure columns are character, not factors
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
l1 <- split(df, cumsum(grepl('TP', df$position)))
lapply(l1, function(i) paste0(i$col[2], paste(sapply(i$col[3:nrow(i)], 
                          function(j) substr(j, nchar(j), nchar(j))), collapse = '')))

#$`1`
#[1] "MGSLSNYALLQLTLTAFL"

#$`2`
#[1] "MVKETTYYDVLGVKPN"

#$`3`
#[1] "MTLGRRLACLFLACVLPA"

#$`4`
#[1] "MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGWV"
```

Even though it gets a bit congested, we can get it to your desired structure,

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(l1, function(i) {dd <- cbind.data.frame(i, join = paste0(i$col[2], paste(sapply(i$col[3:nrow(i)], function(j) substr(j, nchar(j), nchar(j))), collapse = ''))); dd$join <- as.character(dd$join); dd$join[1] <- dd$col[1]; dd$join[3:nrow(dd)] <- ''; dd}))




                                  position             col               join
1.1                                TP<AMT55        TP<AMT55           TP<AMT55
1.2     1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 MGSLSNYALLQLTLT MGSLSNYALLQLTLTAFL
1.3    2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 GSLSNYALLQLTLTA                   
1.4   3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 SLSNYALLQLTLTAF                   
1.5  4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 LSNYALLQLTLTAFL                   
2.6                                TP<AMB88        TP<AMB88           TP<AMB88
2.7     1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 MVKETTYYDVLGVKP   MVKETTYYDVLGVKPN
2.8    2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 VKETTYYDVLGVKPN                   
3.9                                TP<ELANE        TP<ELANE           TP<ELANE
3.10    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 MTLGRRLACLFLACV MTLGRRLACLFLACVLPA
3.11   2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 TLGRRLACLFLACVL                   
3.12  3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 LGRRLACLFLACVLP                   
3.13 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 GRRLACLFLACVLPA                   
4.14                               TP<RACK1        TP<RACK1           TP<RACK1
4.15    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 MTEQMTLRGTLKGHN MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGWV
4.16   2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 TEQMTLRGTLKGHNG                   
4.17  3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 EQMTLRGTLKGHNGW                   
4.18 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 QMTLRGTLKGHNGWV
```

Comment: I get an error saying `Error in nchar(j) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector`

Comment: Make sure your column is `as.character`. It probably is a factor now that's why you get error. I edited my answer

Comment: would It be possible to change the structure and make it like the output? I tried as.data.frame but when the data is huge, I don't know what is what because it misses the title name

Comment: @Learner can you please have a look and If it works for you please accept the answer so we can consider this Q closed. Thanks